# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined (anonymous function) src/Components/Contacts/AddContact.js:62

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[There image from the react debugging tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J76ed.png)

I am new to REACT JS but i bought some Udemy Course and i have been following the tutorials as i also implement but I have have gotten some error and I have failed to figure it out so I don't whether you could of some help my friends.

AddContact.js

```
   render() {
const { name, email, phone, errors } = this.state;
return (
  <Consumer>
    {value => {
      const { dispatch } = value;
      return (
        <div className="card mb-3">
          <div className="card-header">Add Contact</div>
          <div className="card-body">
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this, dispatch)}>
              <TextInputGroup
                label="Name"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Enter Name..."
                value={name}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                error={this.errors.name}
              />
```

TextInputGroup.js

```
const TextInputGroup = ({
    label,
    name,
    value,
    placeholder,
    type,
    onChange,
    error
                      })
```

Comment: `errors` is not defined, can you show us where you declare it?

Comment: Errors is defined in the new set                                                                  this.setState({
      name: "",
      email: "",
      phone: "",
      errors: {}
    });

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Alvaro

Comment: Then you should access `this.state.errors` not `errors`.

Comment: Did you destructure your `errors` from state?
Try to destructure it before like `const {errors} = this.state` or pass `this.state.errors.name` to your `error` prop

Comment: Can you update the question with your `render` or component (AddContact) code?

Comment: do you have errors defined in your `this.state` in the constructor?